# How to add "selected & disabled" option tag inside select tag in Symfony's ChoiceType form?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I have created a custom form type in Symfony 5. This is the class:

```php
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Entity\Species;
use App\Repository\SpeciesRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ProductUploadType extends AbstractType
{
    private $speciesRepository;

    public function __construct(SpeciesRepository $speciesRepository)
    {
        $this->speciesRepository = $speciesRepository;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('species', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => $this->speciesRepository->findAll(),
            'choice_value' => 'name',
            'choice_label' => function (Species $species) {
                return ucwords($species->getName());
            },
            'label_attr' => ['class' => 'label'],
            'mapped' => false,
        ]);

        $builder->add('title', TextType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'input'],
            'label_attr' => ['class' => 'label'],
        ]);

        $builder->add('upload', SubmitType::class, [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'button is-primary'],
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Product::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

It produces the following output (other fields are cut down due to simplicity):

```html
<select id="product_upload_species" name="product_upload[species]">
    <option value="photo">Photo</option>
    <option value="video">Video</option>
</select>
```

But I want something like this:

```html
<select id="product_upload_species" name="product_upload[species]">
    <option disabled selected>-- Choose One --</option>
    <option value="photo">Photo</option>
    <option value="video">Video</option>
</select>
```

With my current implementation (and also by not using form theme), how can I achieve my expectation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a "placeholder":
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#placeholder

You'll also need to set the "required" property to prevent the user from submitting the form with the placeholder "selected":
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#required

```php
$builder->add('species', ChoiceType::class, [
    'required' => true,
    'placeholder' => '-- Choose One --',
    'choices' => $this->speciesRepository->findAll(),
    'choice_value' => 'name',
    'choice_label' => function (Species $species) {
        return ucwords($species->getName());
    },
    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'label'],
    'mapped' => false,
]);
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to add "disabled" attribute?

Comment: I don't think it's possible... but if you add a "required" property to the form item... I think the user will be forced to select something and not be allowed to submit the form with just the placeholder "selected"

Comment: Alright. Thanks for your quick response. I will actually end up making a custom form theme in future, but not now. Symfony's documentations are so big and elaborate that something I just get lost. :P